# gcc l option order?

Tags: c, gcc

`gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include  MyAddressBook.pb-c.c addressbooktest.c -lprotobuf-c -o test`

worked, but

`gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -lprotobuf-c -o addressbooktest addressbooktest.c MyAddressBook.pb-c.c`

didn't.

`man gcc` said that

> For the most part, the order you use doesn't matter.
> Order does matter when you use several options of the same kind; for example, if you specify -L
> more than once, the directories are searched in the order specified.  Also, the placement of
> the -l option is significant.

however I cannot understand how the use of -L and -l option change compile logic.

How can I know where to use -L, -l option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -lprotobuf-c -o addressbooktest addressbooktest.c MyAddressBook.pb-c.c
```

the *linker* (which is a separate program which is invoked by the `gcc` front-end program) runs, it will find the library `protobuf-c` but since no one (yet) uses any functions from it, it will be ignored.